# How can i create entities in Doctrine for my already build two tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, doctrine

Table 1:- 
     --
     -- Table structure for table `page`
     --

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `page`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `page` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `site_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `keyword_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `state` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location_group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uri` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7194 ;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `page`
--
ALTER TABLE `page`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `site_id` (`site_id`,`uri`), 
 ADD KEY `location_group_id` (`location_group_id`), 
 ADD KEY `keyword_id` (`keyword_id`), ADD KEY `uri` (`uri`), 
 ADD KEY `state` (`state`), ADD KEY `location_id` (`location_id`);

 --
 -- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
 --

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `page`
--
ALTER TABLE `page`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=7194;
--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--
--
-- Constraints for table `page`
--
ALTER TABLE `page`
ADD CONSTRAINT `page_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`site_id`) REFERENCES `site` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT `page_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`keyword_id`) REFERENCES `keyword` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
**ADD CONSTRAINT `page_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`state`) REFERENCES `state` (`abbreviation`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,**
ADD CONSTRAINT `page_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`location_group_id`) REFERENCES `location_group` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT `page_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES `location` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Table 2:-

```
--
-- Table structure for table `state`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `state` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `abbreviation` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `territory` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `capital_city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nickname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=56 ;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `state`
--
ALTER TABLE `state`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `abbreviation` (`abbreviation`), 
 ADD UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`), ADD KEY `abbreviation_2` (`abbreviation`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `state`
--
ALTER TABLE `state`
 MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=56;
```

Please check the unique key relationship between the state table and page table and help me how can i identify this relationship during create my new Entity for this type of DB structure.